# Hibernate - session.delete() doesn't set identifier to null

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have 2 classes and they're mapped as 1-to-1

class **B** mapping:

```
<one-to-one class="ClassA" constrained="true" name="a" property-ref="bId"/>
```

class **A** mapping:

```
<property insert="false" name="bId" type="integer" update="false">
      <column length="200" name="BID" not-null="false"/>
 </property>
 <many-to-one class="ClassB"  name="b">
       <column name="BID" not-null="false"/>
 </many-to-one>
```

when i call:

```
A a = (A) session.load(A.class, 1);    
session.delete(a.getB());
```

**B** record gets deleted, but **BID** in **A** stays intact. Why!? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the mapping is n-to-1 (`many-to-one`) not 1-to-1 (`one-to-one`) for class A.

Comment: constrained="true" does nothing?

Comment: so i don't get `Repeated column in mapping for entity`

Comment: Do you have **bId** in **A** or reverse? Which is the parent in this relationship A or B?

Comment: I posted exact mappings. I don't know who's a parent :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Hibernate does not modify the object a. Hibernate can't do it. In the call `session.delete(a.getB())` you give an instance of class B. This instance does not contain any reference to the object a.

You have to change a manually and update it.

An other possibility:

You move the foreign key from A to B (in one-to-one relations it doesn't matter which table has the foreign key). When you delete an instance of B then, you don't need to update A. [Or you use `cascade=all,delete-orphan`, then you can set the reference in a to null and update a, which will force hibernate to delete the instance of B. But I never tried this possibility.]

Comment: Thanks for response. But it seams i can't change it manually cuz i have insert=false update=false in this property. And i cant move foreign key. Please help me!